# CUDA program produces unexpected results

Tags: cuda

I am following the udacity series on parallel computing, which was found on nvidia's website for learning cuda and the first program is computing very strage results.

This code is simply supposed to compute the cube of a number, however the output the program produces is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

__global__ void cube(float * d_out, float * d_in){
    int idx = threadIdx.x;
    float f = d_in[idx];
    d_out[idx]  = f * f * f;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    const int ARRAY_SIZE = 64;
    const int ARRAY_BYTES = ARRAY_SIZE * sizeof(float);
    // generate the input array on the host
    float h_in[ARRAY_SIZE];
    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++) {
        h_in[i] = float(i);
    }
    float h_out[ARRAY_SIZE];

    // declare GPU memory pointers
    float * d_in;
    float * d_out;

    // allocate GPU memory
    cudaMalloc((void**) &d_in, ARRAY_BYTES);
    cudaMalloc((void**) &d_out, ARRAY_BYTES);

    // transfer the array to the GPU
    cudaMemcpy(d_in, h_in, ARRAY_BYTES, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    // launch the kernel
    cube<<<1, ARRAY_SIZE>>>(d_out, d_in);

    // copy back the result array to the CPU
    cudaMemcpy(h_out, d_out, ARRAY_BYTES, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    // print out the resulting array
    for (int i =0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++) {
        printf("%f", h_out[i]);
        printf(((i % 4) != 3) ? "\t" : "\n");
    }

    cudaFree(d_in);
    cudaFree(d_out);

    return 0;
}

    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
-13140721427756115471762456576.000000   0.000000    0.000006    0.000000
0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
0.000000    0.000000    0.000003    0.000000
0.000000    0.000000    -13140721427756115471762456576.000000   0.000000
0.000000    0.000000    0.000006    0.000000
0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
0.000000    0.000000    0.000003    0.000000
0.000000    0.000000    -13140721427756115471762456576.000000   0.000000
0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
0.000006    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
0.000006    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
-13141061438142882086217842688.000000   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000



uname -a
```

produces

```
Linux ubuntu14 3.19.0-43-generic #49~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 31 15:44:49 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

And `nvcc --version`
produces

```
 nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2013 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_Jul_17_18:36:13_PDT_2013
Cuda compilation tools, release 5.5, V5.5.0
```

I installed this from apt-get and I am running a gtx 980 ti

One thing I noticed on the nvidia cuda download site that kernal 3.19 was not explicitly mentioned as being supported on ubuntu 14.04, could this just be a kernel issue? If not any points in the correct direction are appreciated.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: You right, but there is only 1 block being run, so that is no really relevant in this case.

Comment: I am not sure since I am new to cuda, but I don't think that should cause a problem? I think it has to do with my cuda install.

Comment: @talonmies - Fair enough (it's been a **long** time since I used Cuda!)

Comment: The code is correct, but I suggest to examine `cudaError_t` for each API call, especially cudaMalloc, cudaMemcpy and kernel invocation itself. I bet it went wrong at some point. Maybe it's something wrong with your installation, check deviceQuery and memory bandwith samples.

Comment: Your code runs correctly for me. It is probable that you have a broken CUDA installation and nothing is actually working. run your code with cuda-memcheck and see what it reports

Comment: cuda memcheck produced 0 erros and the same results posted above.

Comment: You have CUDA 5.5 installed, with a GTX 980Ti, which isn't a supported card for that CUDA release. I am very surprised no runtime errors are being generated.

Comment: O wow... @talonmies great catch!! Thank you I will reinstall.

Comment: Installed cuda 7.5 and the program worked perfectly! Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code in the question was perfectly correct, however the OP had installed an unsupported CUDA version for his/her GPU model (CUDA 5.5 with a GTX 980Ti). Upgrading to a supported version eliminated the problem.

[Note: This answer has been assembled from comments and added as a community wiki entry to get the question off the unanswered list for the CUDA tag]